# Switch Quantity problem: switch quantity not an integer and could not convert basic_string’ to ‘bool’

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, calculator

I am trying to create a calculator but this happens..
Here's my code. Please help me fix it and give some explanation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    string c;
    string d;
    cout<<"Enter No. 1: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter Operation: ";
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"Enter No. 2: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"So you want me to solve this: ";
    cout<<a<<c<<b;
    cout<<"Type Yes or No";
    cin>>d;
    if(d="yes"){
        switch(c)
    {
        case '+':
            cout << a+b;
            break;

        case '-':
            cout << a-b;
            break;

        case '*':
            cout << a*b;
            break;

        case '/':
            cout << a/b;
            break;
    }
    }
        else{
                return 0;
        }
    
    

}
```

This is the eroor of the code when compiled pleasee fix this code ima noob:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:9: error: could not convert ‘d.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=, std::allocator >(((const char*)"yes"))’ from ‘std::basic_string’ to ‘bool’
     if(d="yes"){
        ~^~~~~~
main.cpp:22:17: error: switch quantity not an integer
         switch(c)
```

Comment: `if(d="yes")` should be `if(d=="yes")`. And you cannot use `std::string` in `switch`. It seems that you wanted `c` to be of `char` type.

Comment: Your "gift" is totally off topic and should be removed.

Comment: Please, take the [tour] and have a look at [ask] if in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it, the test in a switch must be an integer, but you have a string.

Also you are getting confused between `string` which is multiple characters (e.g. "abc") and `char` which are single characters (e.g. 'a', 'b', or 'c').

To fix use just change

```
string c;
```

to

```
char c;
```

This works because you only ever want a single character in `c` so `char` is the appropriate type, and also because `char` in C++ is a kind of integer, so it can be used in a switch.

You have another error here

```
cout<<"Type Yes or No";
cin>>d;
if(d="yes"){
```

First problem is that you ask the user to enter `Yes` or `No` but you test for `"yes"`, `"Yes"` and `"yes"` are not the same string.

Second problem is that the test for equality is `==` not `=`. `=` is used for assignment, which is not the same as testing for equality.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems here:

1. You are providing a `std::string` in switch, this is not possible. You can only pass a character or an integer into it. You could convert that to a `char` type instead.
2. There is one logical error is made in the conditional line (notice comment):

   ```
   if(d="yes") // it should be d == "yes"
   ```